# "Determine how many complete bipartite graphs have n vertices."

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Wouldn't this simply be an infinite number of graphs?

Comment: There are infinitely many only if the names or the actual identity of the vertices mattered. In this context the graphs A-B and X-Y are the same. There is just one complete bipartite graph on two vertices. There are none on three (do you see why? You can count the ones on four vertices by hand.

Comment: Why do you think this is infinite? Maybe it would help you to think about specific cases like $n=4$ for instance.

Comment: Presumably they're asking about some fixed integer $n$, and the answer will be a function of $n$. For instance, how many complete bipartite graphs have 5 vertices?

Comment: I enjoy how these comments, which were posted within 5 seconds of each other, talk about the cases $n=2,3,4,5$ in succession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not quite. You can only have so many graphs.

Let's start with $2$ vertices. The only corresponding complete bipartite would be $K_{1,1}$.

Then, for $3$ vertices, we'd only have $K_{1,2}$.

Then for $4$ vertices, we have both $K_{1,3}$ and $K_{2,2}$.

For $21$ vertices, we have all the way from $K_{1,20}$ to $K_{10,11}$.

In general, there are $\large \displaystyle \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ graphs.